# unable to get json data from server

Tags: javascript, php, json, web-services, cross-domain

My server side code is:

```
$bus = array(
       'meaning' => $name
       );

$jsonstring = json_encode($bus);
echo $_GET['callback'].'(' . $jsonstring. ')';
```

the value displayed on the screen is correct -   `?word=heart({"meaning":"heart"})`
but when I am reading it with following code its printing the value of meaning as `11200665987893779229_1460521505942`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://mydomain?callback=?','word=heart',function(res){
     document.getElementById('print').innerText=''+res.meaning;
    });
});
```

but when I do this:

```
$bus = array(
       'meaning' => 'heart'
       );
```

it's printing the correct value i.e `heart`

I am not getting why this is happening and how to get the correct value *(I am accessing data from my different domain)*.

Comment: $name = substr($_GET['callback'],6);
i have printed its value and it's heart

Comment: problem may be in this line  `echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $jsonstring. ')'; ` did you think its correct

Comment: it is correct , it's printing this
?word=heart({"meaning":"heart"})
as i mentioned everything is working fine but if i use a variable lie $name="heart" instead of using "heart" directly it's printing some code on client side but result is still printed correctly by echoing on screen on server side

Comment: try this in success callback  `console.log(res)`

Comment: `$bus = array(); $bus['meaning'] = $name` and then access it

Comment: can you show your network tab snapshot?

Comment: i am on a free hosting site without command line
can you show me a working example which returns a user defined variable as json

Comment: man i mean your browser console tab

Comment: add quotes in $name variable may be which will work

Comment: even that is not working

Comment: try to console.log(res) and see if it return json object or not?

Comment: it's printing this
Object {meaning: "112003844644431846105_1460523934371"}

Comment: did  your just return your `$name` and check what it have?

Comment: i have echoed it and "heart" is printed then i make that echo statement a comment

Comment: it's a syntax error i think

Comment: From what I can see the issue is with the javascript call, `res` is not returning what you're expecting. Since this is a cross-domain call I would expected that the return url would look something like _callback? 11200665987893779229_1460521505942_. [Have a look in the networks tab of your browser to see what's being returned](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading?hl=en)

Comment: this is being returned 

JQuery1120030792344501622915_1460524412063({meaning: "1120030792344501622915_1460524412063"})
meaning

:
"1120030792344501622915_1460524412063"

Comment: any other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() converts any JSON String passed into the function, to a JSON Object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('http://mydomain?callback=?','word=heart',function(res){
obj = JSON.parse(res);
 document.getElementById('print').innerText=''+obj.meaning;
});
```

});

[a similar post is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o